# Java Dynamic Proxy

Tags: java, dynamic-proxy

what is java dynamic proxy,lot of tutorials are there but they are confusing me ,where we are using this concept , any one explain with real world application usage

Comment: real time != real world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps [the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/reflection/proxy.html) can offer some input:

> Dynamic proxy classes are useful to an application or library that needs to provide type-safe reflective dispatch of invocations on objects that present interface APIs. For example, an application can use a dynamic proxy class to create an object that implements multiple arbitrary event listener interfaces-- interfaces that extend `java.util.EventListener`-- to process a variety of events of different types in a uniform fashion, such as by logging all such events to a file.

It also provides several examples.